# Issue with binding custom DependencyProperty to ListView.SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm having an issue with a binding that I'm trying to implement. It will update the DP once, but after that, it's never updated again.

In XAML I have two controls binding to a listview.selected item.

`<controls:MapControl DataContext="{Binding ElementName=availableMapsListView, Path=SelectedItem}" MapData="{Binding .}">`

and

`<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding ElementName=availableMapsListView, Path=SelectedItem}" Text="{Binding Name}" />`

The textblock update as expected with each change of the listview's selected item.

My custom control creates the dependency property like so:

```
public class MapControl : UserControl
{
  public MapData MapData
    {
        get { return (MapData)GetValue(MapDataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MapDataProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MapDataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MapData", typeof(MapData), typeof(MapControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                null,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnMapDataPropertyChanged),
                new CoerceValueCallback(OnMapCoerceValue)
            )
        );

    private static void OnMapDataPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue != null)
        {
            ((MapControl)source).MapData = (MapData)e.NewValue;                
        }
    }

    private static object OnMapCoerceValue(DependencyObject dpo, Object obj)
    {           
        return obj;
    }
    ...
}
```

I'm pretty much at my wits end and not sure what I should do from here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve or why your code appears so convoluted. If you explain more someone may be able to provide you with a much simpler solution.

That said, by the sounds of it the problem is simply that you're overwriting the binding with a local value. This looks like the culprit:

```
((MapControl)source).MapData = (MapData)e.NewValue;
```

When you do this, the `MapControl.MapData` property will no longer be bound to '.' Instead, it will take on whatever value you've assigned. So your `MapControl.DataContext` property is likely perfectly correct, but it's not being transferred to the `MapData` property because you've destroyed the binding.

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the culprit. As soon as I took that line out, it was working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error last week. My solution was simple : When you explicitly define a `DependencyProperty` you must also explicitly define the mode to TwoWay.

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding ElementName=availableMapsListView,
 Path=SelectedItem}"
 Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```